# pyqt: why the loaded qss file do not work

Tags: pyqt, qtstylesheets

I am loading qss file in my project. And I find it do not work.

My qss file is:

```
QMainWindow
{
    font-size: 20px;
    background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

My code is:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

import sys

class Win(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        with open('style.qss', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            str = file.read()
        self.setStyleSheet(str)

        self.__widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.__widget)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Win()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

However, the background color of showed window is not red.

-------------------- update --------------------------------------

According to the suggestion of @musicamante, I try that add a overwrited QWidget in the QMainWindow. However, it still do not work.

Comment: Is the first line with `# style.qss` included in the file? If that's so, that is a syntax error, as `#` is *not* used for comments, but is a reserved character of stylesheet syntax (it's used as the object name selector). Comments in stylesheet use the `/* ... */` syntax.

Comment: No, the ```#style.qss``` is not included in the qss file. The qss file do not work even I remove the ```#style.qss```.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**style.qss**

```
font-size: 20px;
background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
```

or like this:

**style.qss**

```
QMainWindow {
    font-size: 20px;
    background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: The first qss work. But the second do not work. However, I perfer the style of second qss file, because I can add the style for button or label.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code:

1. when using the curly brackets (`{ property: value; }`) syntax, the *selector* is mandatory (see the [selector types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types)), otherwise no brackets should be used *at all* (but that's usually frown upon);
2. when styling a plain QWidget, the `paintEvent()` **must** be overridden (see the related [QWidget reference on the stylesheet documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#qwidget-widget));

With the given code, the stylesheet syntax should be the following (note the asterisk):

```
* {
    font-size: 20px;
    background: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

When styling a basic QWidget (or a QWidget subclass created in python), the following is also required:

```
class SomeCustomWidget(QWidget):
    # ...
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        opt = QStyleOption()
        opt.initFrom(self)
        self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_Widget, opt, qp, self)


class Win(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # ...
        self.__widget = SomeCustomWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.__widget)
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindly reply. First, the qss file has been revised as: ```QMainWindow{...}```. I have updated my question. More important, my window is a ```QMainWindow``` rather than a ```QWidget```, and the ```paintEvent()``` do not work.

Comment: @QiangZhang Can you please clarify? The `paintEvent()` of a QMainWindow is **not** the same as a standard QWidget, especially if you set a central widget. Please consider that changing the "source" of a code snippet in a question might drammatically change the result of your issue (and, then, the possible answers). Then, did you *actually* set a `SomeCustomWidget` instance as the central widget? [see the update]

Comment: I have update the question according to your suggestion, and it still do not work.

Comment: Please do not edit the question if the modifications are related to an answer that still doesn't satisfy you or doesn't solve your issue: it makes the whole post *very* confusing. Comments are used exactly for this. That said, starting with your given code, with my suggested modifications and the correct css syntax, it works. Can you please check again, using the code in this post (**not** your own)? Also, if you are using the `QMainWindow` selector, the stylesheet will obviously **not** work on a QWidget.

Comment: According to your suggestion, I have revised the qss file as ``` *{...}```, and overwrite the Qwidget as ```SomeCustomWidget```. Finally, the window do not show red background.

Comment: Can you post your current code on some pastebin website or github gist?

Comment: I have posted my current code to github (https://github.com/zhang-qiang-github/qssTest). And the environment is: win 10, pyqt5 5.14.0, pyqt5-sip 12.7.0, pyqt5-tools 5.13.0.1.5.

Comment: I don't know what could that be, it works fine for me (I'm on Linux, but that shouldn't change that much). Can you try with the other available QStyles? You can get a list by calling `QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.keys()`, the most css-compliant is usually the "fusion" style: `app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create('fusion'))`, just after creating the app and *before* setting the stylesheet (shouldn't be a problem, but better safe than sorry).

Comment: Finally, I find what's wrong with my code. The main problem is that the qss file has something wrong. After ```str=file.read()```, the str[0]=''. Most important, the str[0] is not a empty character. I don't know what is this. Finally, I re-create a new qss file, and it work.

Comment: What `str[0]`? There's no trace of that on your code. In any case, using `str` for a variable name is a *very bad idea*.

Comment: ```str``` is the string read from qss file (```str=file.read()```). The first character of of the ```str``` is a very stranger character. I build a new qss file, and everything is OK.

Comment: So, at the end, the answer is correct. If you have "strange" characters you cannot identify, we are not able to help you. That said, really, do *not* use `str` as a variable name.

Comment: @g2m.agent your comment is almost useless, without any context: what are "these"? And in what context they don't work? Are you sure you're having the same problem? You *must* be more clear!