# my .qss file cannot be applied to my .ui file

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, pyside2

I have a `.ui` file made with Qt Designer. It's very simple, only one QWidget and one QLabel, without any Qt Style Sheet code
[image]

I have another `.qss` file with only one line:

```css
background: rgb(39, 44, 54);
```

I want to combine them together, this is my code:

```py
# This is a "demo" of the file path.
# and I'm 100% sure that the original path is working.
UI_FILE = "untitled2.ui"
QSS_FILE = "test.qss"

class MyWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        """
            load UI file and QSS file
        """
        ui_file = QFile(UI_FILE)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader = QUiLoader()
        self.ui = loader.load(ui_file, parentWidget=self)
        ui_file.close()

        style_file = QFile(QSS_FILE)
        style_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        styleSheet = str(style_file.readAll())
        self.setStyleSheet(styleSheet)
        style_file.close()

        """ this button and text edit are used to 
        confirm whether qss is loaded. 
        """
        bt = QPushButton("show style sheet")
        bt.clicked.connect(self.show_sheet)
        self.te = QTextEdit()
        self.te2 = QTextEdit()

        main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.ui)
        main_layout.addWidget(bt)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.te)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.te2)

    def show_sheet(self, clicked):
        self_ss = self.styleSheet()
        self.te.setText(self_ss)

        ui_ss = self.ui.styleSheet()
        self.te2.setText(ui_ss)

## run

if __name__ == '__main__':

    if not QApplication.instance():
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QApplication.instance()

    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

this is my result:
Qt Style Sheet is not working, but when I click the "show style sheet", I can see that `.qss` has been loaded. 
[image]

I tried to change the qss code to this, but it didn't work.

```css
QWidget{
    background: rgb(39, 44, 54);
}
```

I tried to use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65448877/pyqt-why-the-loaded-qss-file-do-not-work/65453248?noredirect=1#comment117042397_65453248) to custom `paintEvent()`, but it didn't work either.

In theory, as long as I set style sheet at the top level, the controls below will inherit. but it doesn't seem to be the case.

**UPDATE**: .ui file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>352</width>
    <height>218</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
     <property name="minimumSize">
      <size>
       <width>0</width>
       <height>100</height>
      </size>
     </property>
     <property name="font">
      <font>
       <family>Arial</family>
       <pointsize>18</pointsize>
      </font>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>TextLabel</string>
     </property>
     <property name="alignment">
      <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Isn't the .ui file plain text? Can't you just paste it in to your question?

Comment: @SuperStormer I updated the code of .ui file.

Comment: The fact that the shown text is displayed as a string representation with raw prefix, quotes and escapes should be a clear hint. `QFile.readAll()` returns a QByteArray, you can't convert it just by using `str`. You either use standard python file access, or convert it with `bytearray(data).decode()`.

Comment: @g2m.agent That a question is a duplicate does not mean that they are going to eliminate it (note that who answered, I mean, it was who closed your post as a duplicate). The duplicate only indicates that the problem is similar, nothing more. It does not indicate that your post is bad or that it should be removed. In SO only the duplicates that do not contribute anything are eliminated, and instead yours contributes that a badly formed qss will not be applied

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are incorrectly converting the QByteArray that readAll() returns to a string, you should not use str.

When you use `str(style_file.readAll())` you get `"b'background-color: red'"` instead of `"background-color: red"`.

To convert to string there are the following options:

```py
styleSheet = style_file.readAll().data().decode("utf-8")
```

or

```py
ba = style_file.readAll()
codec = QTextCodec.codecForName("UTF-8")
styleSheet = codec.toUnicode(ba)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You are totally correct! I never think this way.